# CrystalReports for Eclipseにおける不具合について

Tags: java

動作環境 : Windows10 64bit, Eclipse4.8 Photon, Java1.8.0_191, MySQL8.0.13, cr4e_2.0.24

実装したいこと : DB内データの印刷機能

実現できたこと : 印刷機能実装(データ読み込み、プリンタ印刷)

問題点(実現できていないこと) : 「CrystalReport1-viewer.jsp」を「サーバーで実行」するとエラー発生。

エラー内容 :

```
HTTPステータス 500 - Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

メッセージ javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/security/core/server/csi/XSSEncoder

説明 The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

例外
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/security/core/server/csi/XSSEncoder
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:606)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


原因
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/security/core/server/csi/XSSEncoder
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp._jspService(CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp.java:141)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


原因
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/security/core/server/csi/XSSEncoder
    com.businessobjects.report.web.f.for(SourceFile:112)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.e.byte(SourceFile:442)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:223)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:135)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.a(SourceFile:607)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.processHttpRequest(SourceFile:342)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.taglib.ServerControlTag.doEndTag(SourceFile:45)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.taglib.ReportServerControlTag.doEndTag(SourceFile:74)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.taglib.ViewerTag.doEndTag(SourceFile:34)
    org.apache.jsp.CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp._jspx_meth_crviewer_005fviewer_005f0(CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp.java:188)
    org.apache.jsp.CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp._jspService(CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


原因
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.security.core.server.csi.XSSEncoder
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.f.for(SourceFile:112)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.e.byte(SourceFile:442)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:223)
    com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:135)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.a(SourceFile:607)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.processHttpRequest(SourceFile:342)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.taglib.ServerControlTag.doEndTag(SourceFile:45)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.taglib.ReportServerControlTag.doEndTag(SourceFile:74)
    com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.taglib.ViewerTag.doEndTag(SourceFile:34)
    org.apache.jsp.CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp._jspx_meth_crviewer_005fviewer_005f0(CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp.java:188)
    org.apache.jsp.CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp._jspService(CrystalReport1_002dviewer_jsp.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

注意 原因のすべてのスタックトレースは、のログに記録されています

Apache Tomcat/9.0.10

以上

質問本文 : 上記の環境でJavaでCrystalReportsを利用したところ、一部エラーに悩まされています。印刷用のJSPは問題なく実行できるのに、ビューワー用JSPだけエラーが出る原因はどのようなことが考えられますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

直接の原因はservlet コンテナ(上で動作するservlet)から、「 com/sap/security/core/server/csi/XSSEncoder」を解決できないことです。該当のクラスを含むjarファイルを参照可能なクラスローダに載せる必要があります。
確認すべき項目は、
・/WEB-INF/libに該当のJarファイルが存在するか
・環境変数CLASSPATHに該当のJarが存在するか
　→この場合、ローダの委譲関係によっては参照到達不可能なので、気を付けてください。

あと、このあとのはまりポイントとしては、「移譲関係間違えていて参照到達不可能」とかですかね。
経験したケースでは、Warクラスローダ（移譲元)からEarクスローダー（委譲先）上のクラスを参照しようとしてはまったことがあります。そのほかいろいろなケースがあるので、こればかりはきちんと設計をするか、try&Errorで進むしかないかと。

以上です

Comment: ありがとうございます。実はまったく同じ環境で動かしたもう1つのPC上ではちゃんと動作しているだけに、不可解に感じました。両者のlib内のJARファイル、クラスパスを照らし合わせて確認しても見た目は同じになっていまして。 しかしご指摘の通り、やはりファイル関係？でうまくいっていない気がします。インストール時に何か不具合があったのかもしれません。 最悪インストールし直しから試してみようと思います。

Comment: 使っているJDKが８依然のものなら、$JAVA_HOME/ext/の確認、環境変数CLASSPAATHの内容、JAVA_OPTSの比較なども合わせtえやらてみるとよいです。
あと、where javaコマンドの結果とか(Linuxではwhich java）環境変数JAVA_HOMEの内容も。。macであれば、$JVA_HOME/extではないようなので、そこは調べて、内容を確認してください。